# USB Computer protector name

Tags: usb

I have a USB Cord that I keep plugging in and out of back of computer.

I am afraid one day pins on back of my computer port will break. What is the name of the item, that duplicates the port pins in the back, like a small single plug adapter, protects the computer case? Is it USB protector? I forgot the the actual name.

Its not a usb hub, but something smaller.

Comment: Extension cable. But really, unless you unplug/plug it hundreds of times each day, the connectors will outlive your PC.

Comment: hi @DanielB trying to find extension cable, without really an extension, maybe male to female adapter is whats its called

Comment: As @DanielB states, an extension cord is most convenient, since won't have to reach around to the back. There are short USB extenders and right-angle connectors, but they actually put *more* strain on the PC's connector due to leverage. BTW, more likely than the interior connector wearing out is a break in the colder joints to the PCB.

Comment: The reality is a USB hub or extension cable is what you want. A shorter “stub” might exist, but almost 100% unclear what it would be called or even why someone would make it. As others state, USB connectors are resilient. They won’t break. If you are concerned, then a USB hub or extension cable is your best option.